# why i am not getting reference to method is ambiguous in the following code?

Tags: java, jls

I have base or parent class which has method1(int ,int) and method1(double,double) overloaded

```
public class Sub extends Base{
        @overridden
        method1(double,double) {`some manipulation`}
    
        main{
           method1(1,1); //i am not getting Compile Error(reference to method is ambiguous)!in java
        }
}
```

like so but what is the case here?

```
public class Test3{
    public static void JavaHungry(Exception e) {} 

    public static void JavaHungry(ArithmeticException e) {}

    public static void JavaHungry(String s) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JavaHungry(null); // reference to method is ambiguous
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, please format the code properly - as this is not properly viewable as code.

Comment: 1 is an int, not a double

Comment: This is not valid Java code.  Please provide a **complete** compileable example with all necessary classes.  The short answer is that you are not getting an "ambiguous" compilation error because the method call is not ambiguous.  But we can't explain this without a complete example.   Or something from you to say why you think that it *should be* ambiguous.

Comment: @StephenC i have given one example below where i am getting ambiguous method error..thats why i thought here also i will get the same,but now that is clear.

Comment: Put your new example into the question.  But note that this doesn't explain why you >>think<< that your existing example >>should<< be ambiguous.   AND the two examples are different in a number of respects.   If you want a good answer, you are going to have to write a good question.

Comment: I was wondering about this concept but later i realise from JLS that java will see for most specific method for the given parameters.@StephenC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, `int` is represented by `1` and `double` is represented by `1.0`.

Hence when you invoke `method1(1, 1)` it is invoking the method with int arguments.

For Java compiler, this is not ambiguous.

In short, following are the invocations that will happen when you pass these types of values.

`method1(1, 1)` --> int, int

`method1(1.0, 1)` --> double, double (compiler with auto cast the 1 to double)

`method1(1.0, 1.0)` --> double, double